# How to identify mutable objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, immutability, introspection

In my application, at some point, I need to identify mutable objects to handle them appropriately. This turns out to be more difficult than it seems.

If I use `isKindOfClass:[NSMutableString class]` on an `NSString`, all strings appear to be mutable.

If I ask them whether or not they respond to `@selector(appendString:)`, they all do.

If I actually try to mutate them in a `@try`...`@catch`...`@finally` block, the truth is revealed. However it is very inelegant and very slow.

What would be the best course of action?

Comment: You've already tried using `isMemberOfClass[[NSMutableString class]]`?

Comment: Are you trying to identify if the class is actually an `NSMutableString`? If so, have you tried using the `isMemberOfClass:` method instead, which returns `YES` if it's actually a member (but not a subclass) of the class?

Comment: And check out the always-interesting BNR blog: [About Mutability](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/803-about-mutability/)

Comment: i dont know what you will do with the current string but if you want to append or remove sth on the original string you can create a mutablecopy of string and then make changes on that string then you delete the content of original one and copy the manipulated strings content. just an advice

Comment: "... It is very inelegant and very slow" ... and very broken.

Comment: In theory (based on inheritance) `mutableString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]` should be true, but `nonMutableString isKindOfClass:[NSMutableString class]` should be false.  (But Objective-C inheritance occasionally exhibits a degree of inbreeding.)

Comment: Thanks to all for your replies. Looks like this questions is a duplicate. Sorry. I will now look for the answer in the "original" question, if I find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to ignore mutability, you can iterate through the loop and make mutable copies of each string with `-mutableCopy` (which, no matter what, creates NSMutableStrings).  The opposite is true: by sending `-copy` to every object you're guaranteed to get an immutable NSString.  Mutability is, unfortunately, not a cleanly testable concept due to NSString being a class cluster.  Checking for the class with that `@"__NSCFString"` line is disgustingly unsafe, because Apple has the right to change the underlying class at any time.